# How to cross reference data in one table to another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Not sure how to do this, tried join and didn't work.   I have two tables.

Table one:

```
id  name        admin_id  
-------------------------------  
1   admin           1  
2   joeuser         2  
3   administrator   1  
4   Franz           3
```

Table two:

```
id     admin_name  
----------------------------------  
1      adminstrator rights  
2      adminstrator report rights  
3      view only rights
```

how do I get it to do the following:

```
id  name        admin_id  admin_name  
-----------------------------------------  
1   admin           1     adminstrator rights  
2   joeuser         2     adminstrator report rights  
3   administrator   1     adminstrator rights  
4   Franz           3     view only rights
```

Merging the two wont work as the one table is shorter than the other as well as the fact that the first table expands based on number of configured users where as the second table only grows if they add new named rights.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Why join didn't work?  Post your query.

Comment: Show us the JOIN. Tell us what happened. Did you get an error? Did you get unexpected results?  We can't tell what "didn't work" means if you don't tell us.

Comment: youe should use join

Answer (score 1):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` to have all records returned - even those that don't have associated record in the table with the foreign key.

Example would be:

```
SELECT `users`.*, `access`.`admin_name`
FROM `users`
LEFT JOIN `access`
  ON `access`.`id` = `users`.`admin_id`
```

Here's a link for a reference https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/left-join-optimization.html.

Comment: Thanks that worked, although I had tried before and it was just the two tables put together rather than the matching i was looking for.